# Prove $P(X=Y) = 0$ when $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables on the same probability space.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two independent random variable on the same probability space. We assume: 
$$P(X=x) = P(Y=x) = 0$$
and I want to prove $P(X=Y) = 0$. 
But we don't know whether the distribution of r.v-s are continuous or not.

I tried to solve with the fact that $$
P(X = Y) = E(1_{X=Y})$$ 
But unfortunately it didn't work well. How to solve this problem in measure theory-wise?

Comment: If $P(X=x) = P(Y=x) = 0$ for all $x$ then I would have thought both $X$ and $Y$ must have continuous distributions

Comment: Maybe you meant to say that we don' t know about the existence of PDF's. As @Henry commented you stated yourself that both have continuous distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be the distribution of $X$ and $\nu$ the distribution of $Y$.  "Independent" tells us that
$$
\mathbb P\big[(X,Y) \in E\big] = (\mu \otimes \nu) (E) 
$$
for all Borel sets $E \subseteq \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$.  In particular, when $E$ is the "diagonal" $E = \{(x,x) : x \in \mathbb R\}$ we get
$$
\mathbb P\big[X=Y\big] =\mathbb P\big[(X,Y) \in E\big] = (\mu \otimes \nu) (E) 
$$
And by Fubini (or Tonelli),
$$
(\mu \otimes \nu) (E) = \int_\Omega \nu\{y : (x,y) \in E\}\;d\mu(x)
=\int_\Omega \nu\{x\}\;d\mu(x) =\int_\Omega 0\;d\mu(x) = 0 .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your initial approach is correct and works well:$$\mathbb E1_{X=Y}=\int\int1_{x=y}dF_Y(y)dF_X(x)=\int P(Y=x)dF_X(x)=\int0dF_X(x)=0$$

Also we can switch the order of integration and that makes clear that it is enough already to demand that **at least one** (not necessarily both) of the independent rv's has continuous distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu_Y$ the measure induced by $Y$ over $\mathbb R$ (i.e. $\mu_Y(A)=\mathbb P\{Y\in A\}$). Then

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\{X=Y\}&=\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P\{X=y\mid Y=y\}\mu_Y(\mathrm dy)\\
&\underset{(*)}{=}\int_{\mathbb R}\mathbb P\{X=y\}\mu_Y(\mathrm dy)\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
where $(*)$ follow from the independence of $X$ and $Y$.